# Hand off a JWT from Web App to Chrome Extension securely?

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, jwt

Our situation: A Firebase web app does authentication via Twitter, also allows for token-authenticated calls to cloud functions that store data for a given user. We need a way to get information in the context of an arbitrary URL in the browser into that app with the currently logged-in user – much like the Read-It-Later/Pocket extension.

The JWT token via `currentUser.getIdToken` would be everything we need to authenticate calls from the Extension. Also, having users log in again inside the Extension, even if they're already authenticated inside the Web App isn't the best experience. Is there a secure way to communicate that token from our app domain to the Extension? Thank you!

Edit: We explored the possibility to set the JWT as a cookie and then read that cookie from the Extension. This works, extremely practical and simple. However, that cookie is naturally also susceptible to xss attacks.

Edit: Nice! Setting the cookie to "Secure", "HTTP Only" and "Host only" and accessing it via `chrome.cookie` still works! The cookie should be fairly secure and immune to scripting attacks now. Or are we missing something?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Comment: Why not just have the extension snoop on whatever AJAX request your web app is performing to obtain the token? Or just have the extension get it from `currentUser.getIdToken` itself? Your extension already has access to all of that, if it wants it. Why go through additional convolutions to put it somewhere else so the extension can get it from somewhere potentially less secure?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Both methods won't work as we can not expect the web app to be open whenever the extension action is triggered, so there is no tab to communicate with – whereas cookies can always be read out.

Comment: Try using postMessage to pass the ID token between the Chrome extension and web app. You can verify the origin before securely passing it.

Comment: Wondering what you finally decided on using? Why not save the jwt token in localstorage?